# How to take Items from List in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, list

I am trying to take Items that I have already added to a list.

```
        Dim lista As New List(Of String)
        n = 2
        i = 0
        Do While i < n + 1
            Randomize()
            a = Int(Rnd() * 4) + 1
            If a = 1 Then
                lista.Add("1b")
            ElseIf a = 2 Then
                lista.Add("2b")
            ElseIf a = 3 Then
                lista.Add("3b")
            ElseIf a = 4 Then
                lista.Add("4b")
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
```

Lets imagine that the list i got was {2b,4b,1b}. Now i want to know how to get lets say just 2b from the list as a first Item and then delete it from the list.

Comment: If you are going to use `Randomize` and `Rnd` (which you shouldn't) then at least use them properly, i.e. call `Randomize` once and once only. It's purpose is to initialise the random number generator. You don't initialise it every time you generate a number.

Comment: That was not a problem here but thanks.

Comment: I guess what you are trying to achieve is pop first item. If so a possible answer can be found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7169371/2057782

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a good place to use a [`Queue(Of )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Dim item As String

item = queuea.Dequeue
```

But [`List(Of )`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8) has an indexer so you can just use it like an array:

```
Dim item As String

item = lista(0)
' Then remove the first item:
lista.RemoveAt(0)
```

Comment: Right tool for the job is `Queue`, you can remove suggestion about the list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use the .net `Random` class instead of the old VB6 methods. Calling `Random.Next(Interger1, Integer2)` will return an `Integer` equal to or greater than `Integer1` and less than `Integer2`. Note that since the values are so limited there is a good chance of having duplicates in the list.

Although multiple `ElseIf`s will work, a `Select Case` is easier to read and less typing.

I put the contents of the list in a `ListBox` so we could see what was going on. I used the `Remove` method of `List(Of T)` then rebind the `ListBox`.

```vb
Private lista As New BindingList(Of String)
Private rand As New Random

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BuildList()
    ListBox1.DataSource = lista
End Sub

Private Sub BuildList()
    Dim i = 0
    Dim a As Integer
    Do While i < 3 'since n never changes just use the literal value
        a = rand.Next(1, 5)
        Select Case a
            Case 1
                lista.Add("1b")
            Case 2
                lista.Add("2b")
            Case 3
                lista.Add("3b")
            Case 4
                lista.Add("4b")
        End Select
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'Remove from list
    lista.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use `BindingList(Of T)` instead of `List` you don't need to rebind it every time. listbox will detect change and updates itself

Comment: Thanks for that. I thought there was a way but I didn't know about BindingList(Of T).