# Getting Distinct Words From string via ReGex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I need your help in creating a Regex for this. I want that the regex found are placed in an Array.

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldA= @param1, fieldB =@param2, 
                     fieldC = @param3 , fieldD=@param4
               WHERE fieldE=@param5 and fieldF=@param2 and 
                     fieldG = @param6
```

by using this Regex:

```
@\w+
```

i yield these results:

```
Array[0] = @param1
Array[1] = @param2
Array[2] = @param3
Array[3] = @param4
Array[4] = @param5
Array[5] = @param2
Array[6] = @param6
```

What will I do to eliminate `Array[5] = @param2` so I will have the following result?

```
Array[0] = @param1
Array[1] = @param2
Array[2] = @param3
Array[3] = @param4
Array[4] = @param5
Array[5] = @param6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Enumerable.Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) of LINQ.

It would be something like

```
Dim enu As IEnumerable(Of String) = Array.Distinct()

' If you need an array
Dim array2() As String = enu.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to remove a specific element in an array, see the this question: [How can I delete an item from an array in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448103/how-can-i-delete-a-item-from-an-array-vb-net)