# Trouble with manipulating a string of numbers in an array

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am writing a program that manipulates numbers (lottery drawings), and for the life of me I cant figure it out. BTW, I'm a noob with VB.Net. Please let me know if this post is asking to much and I need to break it down into smaller pieces.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have all of the Powerball drawings in a .txt file and I have separated the drawings from the dates and the balls. They are all in a string named UsersNumbers, which is global. I have counted up all of the duplicate numbers and stored them in an Array named FreqGrid(69). I want a grid that shows the most to least drawing frequencies. The array is like this.

(0), 0
(1), 116
(2), 128
(3), 110
(4), 110
(5), 130
(6), 113
(7), 129
etc. (69 numbers total)

I want to sort them out so that the Grid shows the index's and the numbers from highest to lowest, so I can know what numbers are drawn the most and least. I tried using a Dictionary, Lists and Arrays but I cant seem to figure it out. I'm a noob to all of this.

Here's the code I have so far:

Public Class GetNumberFrequency

```
Public Function GetFrequencyGrid() As String

        'Get/Set Variables
        Dim size As Integer = CInt((Globals.UsersNumbers.Length / 3))
        Dim start As Integer = 0
        Dim FreqArray(69) As Integer
        Dim num As Integer = 0


        'Count up digit Frequencies
        For x As Integer = 0 To size - 1
            num = CInt(Globals.UsersNumbers.Substring(start, 3))
            FreqArray(num) += 1
            start += 3
        Next 'Result: (0, 0) (1, 116) (2, 128) (3, 110) (4, 110), etc.
        Return Nothing

        End Function
End Class
```

Comment: a `Dictionary(Of Int32, Int32)` where the key is the ball number and the value is the number of time that has come up would be ideal.  Not for nothing but you should take a moment to go back and accept some of the past answers you have gotten.

Comment: Hi Plutonix - I'm not sure how to accept the previous answers. Do you mean to post a response saying which answer I used to fix the problem?

Comment: See: [Tour], just click the checkmark next to the selected answer.  It shows others that the answer worked for you.  Soon you will also be able to Upvote (click the up arrow) next to any question or answer which informs, enlightens or helps you.  This also helps others find good answers as well as shows that you participate in the process

Comment: I've tried using a Dictionary but I ran into the problem of not being able to sort the values, and since the values are somewhat random I need to do a sort of the frequencies and take the index's with the Frequencies. I also tried switching the frequencies and the index's but I cant do that because the keys must be unique and that's not the case with this list of numbers.

Comment: Then a `List(Of PBCounter)` which would be a class defined as `{Number As Int32, Frequency As Int32}`, then use linq to sort

Answer (score 0):

You could try to split your data into two arrays. I mean the first array contains the id (0, 1, 2, etc) and the second array contains the random number (0, 116, 128, 110, etc).

```
    Dim id() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim randomNumber() As Integer = {0, 116, 128, 110}
    Array.Sort(randomNumber, id)

    For i = 0 To randomNumber.Count - 1
        MsgBox("(" & id(i) & ", " & randomNumber(i) & ")")
        '(1, 0) 
        '(4, 110) 
        '(2, 116) 
        '(3, 128)
    Next
```

This will sort both arrays in ascending order of randomNumber.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I've tried using array but the problem is I cant delete array values and somre of the Frequencies are duplicates so It just rereads values I want to remove. ie when looping through and I get ti (3) 110 I can store the 110, but (04) is also 110 and I need to delete it so it doesn't get read again on subsequent loops and iterations.

Comment: If you need to modify your array, you'll need to copy your data in a new one. You can check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448103/how-can-i-delete-an-item-from-an-array-in-vb-net)